# Getting undefined error when trying to print sum of an element of an array in react ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Getting object is possibly 'undefined' on `order.reduce` line.
Trying to print sum of all the amounts after printing all the amount.

```
<div>
       {orders.map(({ id, totalAmount }) => {
          return (
            <div key={id}>
                 <div>{totalAmount}</div>
             </div>
    )
    })}
     Total: {
          orders.reduce(
              (t, k) => (t + k.totalAmount),
                             0
                       )
                                        }
    </div>
```

Comment: How are you defining the orders array?

Comment: `const [orders, setOrders] = useState<Order[]>([]);`


const getOrders = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        OrderService.fetchOrders(
            (orders: Order[]) => {
                setOrders(orders);
            },
            () => { },
            () => {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        );
    };

Comment: @tiedantebreak when you fetchOrders and setOrders, actually fetching the orders returns array or undefined. I think that's the reason it's happening

Comment: on fetching it return the array and also it is printing all the orders from this line ` <div>{totalAmount}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because TypeScript thinks the array `orders` array can be undefined. To fix this, you can make a check like this

```
const Component = () => {
 return (
  <div>
   {orders && (
    <div>
     {orders.map(({ id, totalAmount }) => {
      return (
       <div key={id}>
        <div>{totalAmount}</div>
       </div>
      );
     })}
     Total: {orders.reduce((t, k) => t + k?.totalAmount, 0)}
    </div>
   )}
  </div>
 );
};
```

Comment: still the same error is coming

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot of the error at imgur.com and send the url here pls?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AIdNw3N

Comment: @tiedantebreak The error isn't happening for the array `orders` but it is actually happening for the property `totalAmount`. You can simply add `?.` instead of `.` when referencing `totalAmount`. Like `k?.totalAmount`. This is known as optional chaining. Check the edited answer